I want to travel with my spouse as she takes PLAB2 exam, what should be my "main purpose of my visit"?
My wife is scheduled to do PLAB 2 exam in the UK in September, I will be sponsoring all her expenses. I would also like to travel with her on this trip and will also cover all my travel costs. We need to be in the UK 3 weeks prior to the exam so she can use this time to prepare for it through some exam coaching academies.
When applying for a visit visa, her reason is clear because she already has the exam booking confirmation. On my application, what exactly should I fill in the question: "Give details of the main purpose of your visit and anything else you plan to do on your trip."?
I was thinking of saying I intend to give her moral support during this period. Is that reason enough? Do I need to provide an itinerary for my activities in those 3 weeks? And if yes, would this conflict my reason of "providing her moral support"? This section is quite confusing and conflicting on my end, any advise on what I should fill in this section? The same will be explained in detail on the cover letter. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

I’m not sure why that section is confusing you. Accompanying your wife is a reasonable premise, whether it will be enough will depend on your circumstances and the usual criteria that typically determine visa approval/denial eg prior travel history, compelling ties to home country. It makes sense to explain how you’ll pass your spare time while your wife is studying/preparing for her exam, it is however not necessary to buy eg tickets to tourist attractions as proof.

"It makes sense to explain how you’ll pass your spare time while your wife is studying/preparing for her exam" - This is exactly what is confusing me! Other than the usual criteria used for visa approval/denial, I feel like this particular aspect would raise questions. Should I have an itinerary of my activities as my wife is studying/preparing for her exam? Would that invalidate my point of me giving her moral support?

Why would it do that? Will you be by her side 100% of the time eg accompanying her on the academic coaching activities (I suspect not)? What will you personally do to pass the time? What might you do together with your wife during breaks from her study? Answer the question as asked, don’t over think it

That makes sense when you ask the questions like that. So basically what you are saying is, I should have an itinerary for my free time when she is studying, and and itinerary for both of us during her breaks from study (evening couple activities like dinner, weekend activities, etc). If I can answer these, then my question would be answered. Right?

Right. Though TBH a great itinerary is the least important aspect IMHO. Convincing UKVI that you have a good reason not to overstay and enough money to support yourself during the visit without working (remotely or otherwise) is much more important.

I hear you, on that note would you consider this convincing?
Reason not to overstay: letter from my employer granting me absence of leave (15 days annual leave and 5 days compassionate leave, so 20 working days in total) with a strict date for returning back to work.
Money: Around  £6,000 readily available in bank account and £36,000 readily available in money market funds. I keep money in MMFs so it can earn interest instead of an ordinary bank account. For the MMF, I will also get a letter from the licensed fund manager. We plan to stay around 21 days. would this be enough proof?

related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168566/my-wife-and-i-are-applying-for-uk-plab-2-visa-is-it-better-to-apply-to-travel

Money on deposit isn't much of a tie to your home country, because money is portable. That you have a job has some weight and it's right to have your employer's express agreement (as you do) to your vacation. OTOH, your wife's being in the UK is a strong negative for your visa application: she is presumably your closest relative, and her presence in the UK will be seen as a situation that'd make your overstaying in the UK more likely than if she were in the home country while you traveled.

Did your wife's UK visa application mention that you would be staying in the home country (I presume Kenya) while she sits the PLAB2 exam? Your presence at home during her UK visit would provide home country ties for her, and could have been important to UKVI's approval of her visa application. You are now saying that this particular fact of her application may not turn out to be true; this might imperil her already-granted visa. Before your file your own application, consider consulting with a UK solicitor who deals with UK visa issues.

In her application, she mentions that I will travelling with her. Any idea where I can access a UK solicitor for UK visa issues?

Many Travel.SE questions have addressed this issue. Use the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page, and search for "Find UK Solicitor."  One useful Q&A is this one.
